# How do i integrate websockets communication to a web app?

Tags: flask, websocket, uwsgi

I want to create a multiplayer web-game. Basically it will be a simple web app, but i plan to use websockets for players to find a game and for the game part itself. I am using docker, nginx+uwsgi+flask and vue.js for frontend. But I'm not sure where should I place the websockets logic part on my backend. Should I somehow integrate it in the flask app? Or should I have a separate websocket server? How do I share logic (e.g. ORM models) between flask and websockets app then?